# arrow, diagrams.sty (Paul Taylor)

Tags: diagrams, arrows

My code follows:

```
\documentclass[]{book}

\usepackage[silent,nohug,heads=LaTeX,midshaft]{diagrams}

\newarrow{Dashto}{}{dash}{}{dash}>
\newcommand{\undera}{\underline{a}}
\newcommand{\Spec}{\mathop{\mathrm{Spec}}}

\begin{document}

By the Chain Lemma (2),
the function field of $S(\root{\ell}\of \gamma)$ splits $\undera$.
If $X$ is a norm variety for $\undera$,
there is a finite field extension
$F'$ of $k(S(\root{\ell}\of \gamma))$ of degree prime to $\ell$
and an $F'$-point $\Spec(F')\to X$. Forming $\tilde{S}$ as in
Lemma~3, this $F'$-point extends to a rational map
$\phi:\tilde{S}(\root{\ell}\of \gamma)\rDashto^{}X$.

Recall that the cyclic group $C_\ell=\langle\sigma\rangle$ acts on
$X^\ell$ by $\sigma(x_1,...,x_\ell)=(x_2,...,x_\ell,\break x_1)$, and that
$C^\ell X$ denotes the geometric quotient variety $X^\ell/C_\ell$.
Let $\sigma$ be a generator of $C_\ell$, 
and let $\phi:\tilde{S}(\root{\ell}\of \gamma)\rDashto^{}X$
be the rational map mentioned above. 
Choosing an isomorphism $C_\ell\cong\mu_\ell$, the rational maps
$\phi\sigma^i$ assemble to form a $C_\ell$-equivariant rational map
$g=(\phi,\phi\sigma,...,\phi\sigma^{\ell-1})$
from $\tilde{S}(\root{\ell}\of \gamma)$ to $X^\ell$.

\end{document}
```

I used the tag `\rDashto` two places, but it came with two dashes in one place and three dashes in another place, refer the marked sample for clear understanding. I need to fix three dashes in all places. How to fix it? Advise...

[image]

Comment: Are you tied to diagrams.sty? As far as I can see, `\rDashto` uses `\leaders`, so it is quite normal that the arrow is printed differently according to its position on the line.

Comment: @egreg Yes, I meant exactly what you mean. But I need to fix it with 3 dashes, is it possible?

Comment: I don't think so. If you enclose the diagram in a box (with `\mbox`) you get two dashes. I abandoned `diagrams.sty` several years ago: it's poorly documented and difficult to customize, its code is obfuscated.

Comment: By the way, `\root\ell\of\gamma` should be `\sqrt[\ell]{\gamma}` and `...` should always be `\dots`.

Comment: FWIW, here's a [picture (click)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XnhOe.png) of what I get with `tikz-cd`.

Comment: Thanks for this, if I change this, then the arrow head was totally changed, but I should match the output what I shown....sorry for giving more trouble.... Happy New Year...

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sO7dA.jpg how to fix error? thank you very much

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE... Please download the recent version of `diagrams.sty`, which fix the issue...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `diagrams.sty` package is difficult to customize and its code is obfuscated, so it is really hard to change its output.

I can suggest you to use `tikz-cd` instead.

```
\documentclass[]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\newcommand{\undera}{\underline{a}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Spec}{Spec}

\newcommand{\ratmap}[3]{%
  \begin{tikzcd}[
    arrow style=tikz,
    >=LaTeX,
    ampersand replacement=\&,
    sep=scriptsize,
    cramped,
  ]
  #1\colon #2 \arrow[r,dashed] \& #3
  \end{tikzcd}%
}

\begin{document}

By the Chain Lemma (2),
the function field of $S(\sqrt[\ell]{\gamma})$ splits $\undera$.
If $X$ is a norm variety for $\undera$,
there is a finite field extension
$F'$ of $k(S(\sqrt[\ell]{\gamma}))$ of degree prime to $\ell$
and an $F'$-point $\Spec(F')\to X$. Forming $\tilde{S}$ as in
Lemma~3, this $F'$-point extends to a rational map
\ratmap{\phi}{\tilde{S}}{X}.

Recall that the cyclic group $C_\ell=\langle\sigma\rangle$ acts on
$X^\ell$ by $\sigma(x_1,\dots,x_\ell)=(x_2,\dots,\allowbreak x_\ell, x_1)$,
and that $C^\ell X$ denotes the geometric quotient variety $X^\ell/C_\ell$.
Let $\sigma$ be a generator of $C_\ell$, 
and let \ratmap{\phi}{\tilde{S}}{X}
be the rational map mentioned above. 
Choosing an isomorphism $C_\ell\cong\mu_\ell$, the rational maps
$\phi\sigma^i$ assemble to form a $C_\ell$-equivariant rational map
$g=(\phi,\phi\sigma,\dots,\phi\sigma^{\ell-1})$
from $\tilde{S}(\sqrt[\ell]{\gamma})$ to $X^\ell$.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Some things to note:

1. I changed all `...` to `\dots`;
2. `\root\ell\of\gamma` is foreign syntax, the proper LaTeX syntax is `\sqrt[\ell]{\gamma}`;
3. it's better to use `\colon` for maps, instead of `:`.

Comment: Many thanks, your hat is superb, Happy New Year...

Comment: In addition to @egreg's excellent advice, I would also point out the Taylor's `diagrams` package contains a time bomb which always seems to kick in when it is least expected and wanted. Moreover, if for any reason you have to submit a TeX file that uses `diagrams.sty` to a publisher, it may pose problems on their end. Just a thought...

Comment: @sgmoye Yes, I agreed your words, will take care...thanks for the notification...Happy New Year....